# Php array reading

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an issue with my code i wanna read an array like this,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => 'Da Siick f0rest ;'
            [Frags] => 2
            [Time] => 2616
            [TimeF] => 43:36
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => ReTrY
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 7004
            [TimeF] => 01:56:44
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => huFFle.
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 434
            [TimeF] => 07:14
        )
)
```

I tried with code like this to read the array, but does not work. I tried to echo the string $player_nickname but it does not show me the results.

```
    <?php $players = file_get_contents('http://gametracker.al/../../Example.php?ip='.$server_ip.'&port='.$server_port.'');


        foreach ($players as $Player) {

            $player_nickname        = mysql_real_escape_string($Player['Name']);

            $player_score           = mysql_real_escape_string($Player['Frags']);

            $player_time            = mysql_real_escape_string($Player['TimeF']);

            $player_nickname        = (!empty($player_nickname)) ? $player_nickname : 'anonymous';

echo $player_nickname;

        } ?>
```

Thanks everybody.

Comment: You have  a file  or an array ?   . if you have a file  you should eval the content like a sequence of rows .. not like an associative array

Comment: it's working:-https://eval.in/685646

Comment: What happens? Do you get a 500 possibly because `mysql_` is not defined? Is `$players` populated?

Comment: scaisEdge i used print_r  `print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ) );`

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is deprecated and it has been removed on PHP7. Have you not enabled showing error messages by editing php.ini in dev environment?

Comment: i tryed `echo $Player['Name'];` but again dont work.

Comment: Have you not enabled showing error messages by editing php.ini in dev environment?

Comment: http://gametracker.al/gp/Examples/Example.php?ip=176.57.188.22&port=27022

Comment: most often it should be because of some strings which have not been wrapped by ''.
ex. [TimeF] => 43:36,
[Name] => ReTrY and etc. 

check above online code to see how to fix them

Comment: I don't think that strings are the issue, if you are them directly with a DB. try var_dump($Query->GetPlayers()); and check the data types. BTW have you not enabled showing error messages by editing php.ini in dev environment? and can't you see any error messages?

Comment: i changed it to var_dump but again dont get any results

Comment: $playersData = $Query->GetPlayers();
if (!empty($playersData)) {
  echo 'You get data';
} else {